# I got null parameter in Java when I try to apply OpenCV?

Tags: java, opencv, error-handling, nullpointerexception, netbeans-8

```
 public EllipseParam detectAndDisplay(BufferedImage img, CascadeClassifier faceCascade) {
   // EllipseParam openCV;
    Point center = null;
    double width = 0;
    double height = 0;

    Mat image = ImagePreProcessing.bufferedImageToMat(img);

    // -- Detect faces
    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect(); 
    faceCascade.detectMultiScale(image, faces);

    List<Rect> listOfFaces = faces.toList();
    for (Rect face : listOfFaces) {
        center = new Point(face.x + face.width * 0.5, face.y + face.height * 0.5);
        width = face.width*0.5;
        height = face.height*0.5;

        System.out.println("OpenCV: " +center);
        System.out.println("wid:" +width);
        System.out.println("hei:" +height);
        EllipseParam openCV = new EllipseParam(center, width, height);
        System.out.println("value on EllipseParam: " +String.valueOf(openCV));
        return openCV;
    }
    return null;
}
```

----- in the EllipseParam class

```
public class EllipseParam {
public double x;
public double y;
public double a;
public double b;
public double theta;
public Point center;
public double width;
public double height;

public EllipseParam(double x,double y,double a,double b,double theta){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.theta = theta;
}

public EllipseParam(Point center, double width, double height){
    //this.image = image;
    this.center = center;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
```

I try to setting parameter and getting that, but output I got is like this:

OpenCV: {196.5, 156.5}

wid:147.5

hei:147.5

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

value on EllipseParam: entity.EllipseParam@d34c4b

What is wrong with my code?

I read the answer, but its not solve my issue actually. Can you explain to me more?

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace. At the moment we can't tell enough about where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: Why do you return null from the method?

Comment: @JonSkeet oke I try.

Comment: @MichaelDz I tried to apply somecode for different result from my original code I made...but the reason I not really know